# Eldat easywave usbserial device not detected on raspberrypi 3

Tags: usb, serial

I have a raspberrypi 3. If I put a usb serial rfxcom device in the USB port I get a ttyusb0 serial device with ftdi drivers, but I have another USB stick with serial interface easywave which does nothing, on a windows computer it is a serial device. How can I let my pi 3 see it as a serial device?

i am running

Linux JillesPI02 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch)
Release:    9.3
Codename:   stretch

```
[ 1221.371631] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1221.371640] usb 1-1.2: Product: RFXtrx433
[ 1221.371647] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: RFXCOM
[ 1221.371655] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: A11SERXI
[ 1221.407993] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[ 1221.408038] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[ 1221.408080] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[ 1221.416081] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[ 1221.416155] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[ 1221.416355] ftdi_sio 1-1.2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 1221.416625] usb 1-1.2: Detected FT232RL
[ 1221.418252] usb 1-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1240.632004] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1240.632602] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1240.632677] ftdi_sio 1-1.2:1.0: device disconnected
[ 1243.486924] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[ 1243.624734] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=155a, idProduct=1006
[ 1243.624749] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1243.624758] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Transceiver Easywave
```

i know the usb stick Easywave from Eldat should use the

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/783daf505c2d8ecf26eeb4b4cd657f4b48072540/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.c

but the descripters for the usb easywave device aint formulated on the silicon labs  driver

i added them in a pull request for the linux distribution , it is a bridge to far for me to update the driver itself in my pi 3 ,

https://github.com/nattlip/linux/commit/3f153b96bf2315b10a02b5ce486ae9bc447af8b3

a workaround is mentioned on stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330155/updating-product-vendor-id-on-raspberry-pi-cp210x

Comment: You have to reformat the question, its unreadable, and "pi 3", please spell it out, it will improve your chanses to get help!

Comment: If you told us the model and log of the other device instead of that of the one that works for you, we could maybe help.

Comment: Does this help? https://wiki.fhem.de/wiki/RFXtrx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the right answer thanks to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330155/updating-product-vendor-id-on-raspberry-pi-cp210x

if you know the right descriptors of the device id and vendor id you can add them simply on your pi with

```
§ sudo modprobe cp210x
§ sudo sh -c 'echo 155a 100D > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp210x/new_id'
§ sudo sh -c 'echo 155a 1013 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp210x/new_id'
§ sudo sh -c 'echo 155a 1006 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp210x/new_id'
```

update 29-04-2018

the rx09 usb stick with id 1006 is now in the offical linux kernel 4.9 , so if you update and upgrade your pi2 it should work without modprobe.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo modprobe ftdi_sio
sudo modprobe usbserial
```